# Can multiple InfoPath forms read/write the same SharePoint lists

Tags: 2013, infopath

Background: Sharepoint 2013/Infopath 2013; very new to both

We have an Infopath form (form A) that read/writes to a SharePoint list (SP List A).

Can we have another InfoPath form (form B) that updates the same  SharePoint list (SP List A)? If so how is it done?

Comment: You can create saparate InfoPath form for each content type so use two different content type for one list in that way you can create two form for one list

Answer (score 1):

No you can't , instead You can use multiple views to Target the same list

Check https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB